# Sorting, Customizing and Generating with Raw Data or Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, list, report

I have a list of Customers records , may be in thousands ,

I want to generate reports (Crystal or MS ) like in hierarchy.

it should be something like this

Customer By country , then Customer by City with in a Country , Then Customers in Areas , and then Male and Female in those area.

I also want to show customer plusminus Calculated from Top .

Like 4 Customer like in NYC and all have +500 , so I have value in US 2000;

**any Idea , Hint algorithm how I can achieve this?**

here is the Customer Object and example Customers .

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CutIND { get; set; }
    public string CustName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int plusMinus { get; set; }
}
```

and example customers

```
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        c1.CutIND = 123445;
        c1.CustName = "Sajjad";
        c1.Country = "US";
        c1.City = "NYC";
        c1.Area = "BLueArea";
        c1.plusMinus = -560;


        Customer c2 = new Customer();
        c2.CutIND = 43432;
        c2.CustName = "Mike";
        c2.Country = "UK";
        c2.City = "London";
        c2.Area = "SomeArea";
        c2.plusMinus = 9000;
```

Comment: As for sorting, you can always implement `IComparable` or `IComparer` that "describes" your "hierarchical" sort and use `Array.Sort` or `List.Sort`. Somewhat similar customization can be done with `Enumerable.OrderBy` as well. I'm not sure that just *sorting* is what you actually need, though. It seems to me you need to design a whole new hierarchical data structure capable of supporting your UI needs.

Comment: what do you think this logic will work ?

i create a object

like

Main Object  - > Object of Countries > object of Cities > object of areas > and object of customer.

create a single object with help of loops , and the main object contains all data hierarchical .

what do you think this logic will work  ?

Comment: "Customer By country , then Customer by City with in a Country , Then Customers in Areas , and then Male and Female in those area" seems to describe a sort criteria. You could just sort by this criteria and spit out the report, but you seem to want some grouping and "beautification" of this data, hence my suspicion you'll not be able to get away just with this simple approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ queries to relatively easily group data hierarchically at multiple levels.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Customer
  {

     public int CutIND { get; set; }
     public string CustName { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Area { get; set; }
     public string Gender { get; set; }
     public int plusMinus { get; set; }
     public Customer(int CutIND, string CustName, string Country, string City, string Area, string Gender, int plusMinus)
     {
        this.CutIND = CutIND;
        this.CustName = CustName;
        this.Country = Country;
        this.City = City;
        this.Area = Area;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.plusMinus = plusMinus;
     }
  }


  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Customer[] customers = new Customer[] {
           new Customer(123445, "Sajjad", "US", "NYC", "BLueArea", "M", -560),
           new Customer(43432, "Mike", "UK", "London", "someArea", "M", 9000),
           new Customer(20001, "Mathilde", "OS", "Vienna", "WienerWald", "F", 8192),
           new Customer(20002, "Harry", "US", "NYC", "Broooklyn", "M", 50),
           new Customer(20003, "Jim", "OS", "Vienna", "AIS", "M", 12000),
           new Customer(20004, "Bill", "US", "MSP", "Excelsior", "M", 90)
        };

        var CityGroups =
           from c in customers
           group c by new { Country = c.Country, City = c.City } into cities
           select new { Country = cities.Key.Country, City = cities.Key.City, Total = cities.Sum(c => c.plusMinus), Residents = cities };

        var CountryGroups =
           from city in CityGroups
           group city by city.Country into countries
           select new { Country = countries.Key, Cities = countries, Total = countries.Sum(c => c.Total) };

        foreach (var country in CountryGroups)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("{0} (Total = {1})", country.Country, country.Total);
           foreach (var city in country.Cities)
           {
              Console.WriteLine("  {0} (Total = {1})", city.City, city.Total);
              foreach (var r in city.Residents)
              {
                 Console.WriteLine("    {0} {1} {2} {3}", r.Area, r.CustName, r.Gender, r.plusMinus);
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: its look like Great , let me try and get back to you